# Starting Docker container in interactive mode in shell

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created Dockerfile with the following content,

```
FROM node:16.4.2-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

COPY . /app
```

then I created image,

```sh
docker build -t app:0.1 .
```

and then started the container by running,

```sh
docker run -it app:0.1
```

It opened the **node shell**.

I then closed it.

Doing `docker ps -a` gives the following output,

[image]

---

Now,

I want to restart the same container and with **node shell**. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

It shows as exited since there is no process running. To start it again , you can use the `docker start` command with `-i` flag.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/ for more options

Answer (score 1):

`docker rm` the existing container and `docker run` a new one.  Consider using the `docker run --rm` option so the container deletes itself when it's done.

There's nothing special or valuable about a container; it's just a wrapper around a single process (in your case the Node REPL), and creating a new one isn't especially expensive.  In the same way that you can't restart the REPL once you've exited it but need to re-run `node`, you generally will want to delete and recreate containers once their process has finished.  With longer-running processes this also helps ensure the process's filesystem is exactly what you expect: if something exits unexpectedly, deleting the container will also remove any temporary files or lock files it's left behind, so restarting the container will run successfully.

Comment: This statement,

`There's nothing special or valuable about a container; it's just a wrapper around a single process (in your case the Node REPL), and creating a new one isn't especially expensive`

resolves lots of my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the following sequence of commands:

```
docker container start magical_merkle
docker attach magical_merkle
```

**Explanation:** the first command restarts your exited container, but in detached mode, it means it's running in the background and you can't see it's output. now for you to reattach to the container you run `attach` command of docker (second command) which attaches the std io of your host terminal to the std io of the running container.

you may notice the `magical_merkle` in the commands. this is the name of your container as found in the `container ls` output you provided. when you run the `run` command, docker will name the container with a auto generated name if you don't provide one for it.